# How to restrict Lucene search results to documents containing at least n words?

Tags: java, search, lucene

I would like to restrict the search results to documents containing at least `n` tokens/words, i.e. the result set must contain documents with at least `100` tokens. I've tried to write a custom `LeafCollector` but the API doesn't seem to be intuitive. Before diving deeper I wanted to ask if it is at all possible and if it is, maybe someone could provide a short proof of concept implementation to get me going.

Here is what I have so far, the logic should be in the `collect` method as far as I understand.

```
public class CustomCollector extends TopDocsCollector<ScoreDoc> {
    protected CustomCollector(PriorityQueue<ScoreDoc> pq) {
        super(pq);
    }

    @Override
    public LeafCollector getLeafCollector(LeafReaderContext leafReaderContext) throws IOException {
        return new LeafCollector() {
            @Override
            public void setScorer(Scorer scorer) throws IOException {

            }

            @Override
            public void collect(int i) throws IOException {

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean needsScores() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Collector is not a good idea - this is segment aware data structure and you have to take into account segment switch, did you try boolean should query with minimum should match https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/QueryBuilder.html#createMinShouldMatchQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-float- ? Could you explain your use case in details?

Comment: @IvanMamontov I didn't store the stats how many words each document contains, so a query is not possible as far as I can tell. As a part of my Bachelor thesis I need to index ~300GB of data, I created the index and my supervisor now says that he would like to only consider docs with >100 tokens. I'm trying to go around indexing 300GB of data again just because of this small requirement as it took quite a bit of time to create the index.

Comment: The querying performance is not that important for my use case.

Comment: You can index the number of words in each document while indexing and then query on that field. That would work, no?

Comment: @darcula Yes, that's what I ended up doing. I thought that maybe Lucene stores that kind of info by default and didn't want to create the index again because it took a long time.

Comment: @Buddy That seems difficult to achieve in Lucene because it uses an inverted index as underlying data structure. It stores terms as keys and documents as values. What you are looking for is document -> its terms.